# wirte text through div border

Tags: html, css

I have three div columns with text like this and one main title. My question would be if it possible to write that title through divs borders, that it will be like in one line.

```css
.row {
   display:table-row;
}

.ima{
   display:table-cell;
   width:auto;
   height:200px;
   border:1px solid red;
   padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="ima"><h1>Title. Pavadinimas, su dideliais parasymais.</h1>
      <p>
         Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta.
         Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
   </div>
   <div class="ima">
      <p>
         Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta.
         Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
   </div>
   <div class="ima">
      <p>
         Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. 
         Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I can edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.row {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
}

.ima {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 80px 10px 10px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="ima">
    <h1>Title. Pavadinimas, su dideliais parasymais.</h1>
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is something like i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the html ? If yes, you can simply do that :

```css
.row {}

.ima {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>Title. Pavadinimas, su dideliais parasymais.</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use absolute positioning on your `h1`

```css
.row {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
}

.ima {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 80px 10px 10px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="ima">
    <h1>Title. Pavadinimas, su dideliais parasymais.</h1>
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.ima {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
  padding: 10px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row title">
    <div class="ima" colspan="3">
      <h1>Title. Pavadinimas, su dideliais parasymais.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ima">
      <p>Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.<p>
    </div> 
    <div class="ima">
      <p>Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.<p>
    </div>

    <div class="ima">
      <p>Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.<p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fieldset & legend tag.. you can check below snippet

```css
.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.ima {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  //border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Title. Pavadinimas, su dideliais parasymais.</legend>
<div class="row">  
<div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>

  <div class="ima">
    <p>
      Cia yra paprastas tekstas apie nieka, kad butu uzpildyta paragrafo vieta. Tikiuosi protingi zmones patars teisinga atsakyma.
      <p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
```